# Open bootstrap modal after $http response arrives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am stuck in getting the data coming from a http response to show in a bootstrap modal. The $http.get service of angularjs brings in some response fields, but the modal loadds too quickly to show any of these fields. Sometimes these fields appear but other times it does not. The behavior is random. How can I load the modal with the correct data coming from http response.

Here is my GET call

```
$scope.getfieldsfromJIRA = function(projectkey, domain, auth, username, password){
                    var authenticatedToken = auth +" "+ window.btoa(username+":"+password);
                    projectsettingsfactory.getfieldsfromJIRA(projectkey, domain, authenticatedToken).then(function successCallBack(response){
                        angular.forEach(response.data.projects, function(project){
                            angular.forEach(project.issuetypes, function(issuetype){
                                angular.forEach(issuetype.fields, function(field, key){
                                    $scope.fields[key] = field;// These are the fields which are to be populated as checkboxes
                                    if(field.required){
                                        $scope.requiredfields[key] = field;
                                        $scope.selectedfields[key] = field;
                                    }
                                    if(bugconfiginfo && bugconfiginfo.jirafields[key]){
                                        $scope.checkedfields[key] = true;
                                    }
                                });
                            });
                        });
                        if(Object.keys($scope.fields).length === Object.keys($scope.selectedfields).length){
                            $scope.selectallcheckboxes = true;
                        }
                        $scope.$apply();
                    }, function errorCallBack(response){
                        alerts.error("Error in finding fields");
                    });

            }
```

As you can see, I used $scope.$apply(), but the modal is not refreshed to fetch the updated fields.

Here is my modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" >
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h4 class="modal-title">Configure Fields</h4>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-6">                 
                 <div class="checkbox">
                    <label> <strong>Show Fields</strong>&nbsp;</label>
                   <input type="checkbox" id="select_all" ng-click="multiSelectCheckBox()">
                   <label for="select_all">Select All</label>
                 </div>    
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-6">

               </div>
               <hr/> 
               <div class="col-md-12">
                  <ul class="columns_3 list-unstyled" data-columns="3">
                            <li ng-repeat="(key,field) in fields">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="jirafield{{$index}}" name="{{key}}"
                                        ng-checked="field.required || selectallcheckboxes || checkedfields[key]"
                                        ng-disabled="field.required"
                                        ng-model="field.isActive"
                                        ng-click="checkBoxSelect(key,field)"> <label
                                        for="jirafield{{$index}}">{{field.name}}</label>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
               </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="savefields()">Save</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-cancel" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="clearselectedfields()">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you open modal after you get response ? you can just open modal manually after getting response :

```
jQuery('#myModal').modal('show')
```

Or better set some delay if you think it's required like :

```
setTimeout(function() { 
jQuery('#myModal').modal('show')
}, 1000);
```

Comment: actually the jquery version used in our project does not support .modal() function. Is there some angularjs way to achieve the same?

Comment: if there is one or more modals, will $modalInstance given in the above link, work?.